# excel formula to caluculate the first value

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to calculculate the value of column X at the following table.
The logic is the followings.

1. the value of X = its id itself if the value of A is the first value.
2. the value of X = the id of first A if the value of A is not the first one.

this is the example of the data and the expected results are already filled in column X (Yellow cells).
there are no data in column X at actual data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula is:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH($B1,B:B,0), 1)
```

Where:

- `A:A` - a range is column `A`
- `B:B` - a range is column `B`
- `$B1` prevents shift `B` column but not `row`
- [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) gets value from a `range` by a `row` and `col`(1)
- [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) finds value in range and returns a `row`

[image]

Comment: great, you can still put a green checkmark to the left of the question)